# Dynamic is not working properly

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

I'm having some troubles with the Dynamic command in Mathematica, the next code shows an interactive graphic of the function f(x) = 1 - x^2. The graphic's title also shows the current area under the curve (definite integral) which is modified using the slider.

```
 Manipulate[Show[Plot[1 - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> Integrate[1 - x^2, {x, 0, Limite - 0.000000000001}]],   
 Plot[-x^2 + 1, {x, 0, Limite}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Filling -> Axis] ], {Limite, 0.000000000001, 1}, LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

I would like to show the current area using this command:

```
Integrate[1 - x^2, {x, 0, Dynamic[Limite]}]
```

but the result is not what i expected. Mathematica evaluates this like 
    `0.529 - (0.529)^3 / 3` 
which is correct but i don't understand why it displays an expression instead of a single number.  The `//FullSimplify` and`//N` commands just don't solve the problem.

Is there a better way to obtain the result?

Am I using the Dynamic command correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: The code with `Manipulate` shows a number on my system.

Comment: Works for me with mma 8.0.1 and win7.

Comment: It works, the problem is the difference between the graphic´s title format (0.6667 for example) and the Integrate[1 - x^2, {x, 0, Dynamic[Limite]}] format (0.529 - (0.529)^3 / 3)

Comment: Works for me too (Mathematica 7.0.1, Windows 7). Though at `Limited` equal to its minimum value (`0.000000000001`) it does show an expression. I have tried with `ReleaseHold` - but it seem not to have an effect. There is some fantastic "magic" begin the dynamic frontend. Beautifully documented but quite a science in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example the Integrate command is performed once with a symbolic upper limit.  When the value of that upper limit changes the integral is not recomputed.  You will get your desired result if you move the Dynamic[] wrapper from the iterator specification and wrap it around the Integrate command, which will cause the integral to be recomputed whenever Limite changes.

```
Dynamic[Integrate[1 - x^2, {x, 0, Limite}]]
```